# Deactivate clean-room environment in truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-test, truffle-deployment

Everything is in the question, does anyone have a way to prevent the redeployment of the contract every time you run a test and keep using the same "contract" feature ?

Edit : I've found it, you can use the contract static abstraction API with the .deployed() method or .at() method in order to access already deployed contracts.